# Android gridview don't trigger onItemClickListener

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

I have read many post about this problem, usually due to the inclusion of clickable objects in the gridview but that's not my case. I have a framelayout with a imageview and a gridview, I moves both using ontouchlistener in gridview and it's works, but onItemClickListener don't trigger. My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layoutJuego"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<paricio.toni.caththemole.MyFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fondo"
        android:layout_width="760dp"
        android:layout_height="760dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@android:string/untitled"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/terrenoarena" />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="640dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >
    </GridView>
</paricio.toni.caththemole.MyFrameLayout>
```

MyFrameLayout is a simple framelayout extended to be bigger than screen. My gridview have only imageviews (64 in a 8x8 structure). It was working fine before when I used gridview.setOnTouchListener for moves myFrameLayout but I had shake so I changed to moves imageview and gridview, result? bye bye shake and bye bye onItemClickListener

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    adaptador = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(adaptador);

    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int desplazamiento[]={0,0};
            fondo.getLocationOnScreen(desplazamiento);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mx = event.getX();
                    my = event.getY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    curX = event.getX();
                    curY = event.getY();
                    fondo.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    gridview.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    mx = curX;
                    my = curY;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    curX = event.getX();
                    curY = event.getY();
                    fondo.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    gridview.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, 
                long id) {
            Log.i("miTraza","OnItemClick"); // Don't trigger
                    ...
        }
    });
```

I think that I could get position for gridview cell calculating manually with onTouchListener and events ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP consecutives (without ACTION_MOVE) but I want let it as last option.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you have overridden the touch event itself which means its you who has to handle click events to.

Comment: Have You tried return false for all events (for some You return true) from Yours OnTouchListener? Pass all touch events from where directly to gridview?

Comment: sandrstar, thanks I did before modificate. If I put in false I get onClick fires but views are not moving together anymore. I try of work from here. Andro Selva thanks too, it's my last option.

Comment: I'm lost. With return true It moves well but I don't get trigger in OnItemClickListener, With ACTION_UP return false I moves well and OnItemClickListener triggered but position is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to perform manually OnItemClick inside OnTouch. This is the code I used, the method adaptador.getPosition (gridview, (int) x, (int) m) returns the selected position on the screen click. I've tried using pointtoposition (int, int) but returns me the wrong position.

```
    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int desplazamiento[]={0,0};
            fondo.getLocationOnScreen(desplazamiento);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    click = true;
                    mx = event.getX();
                    my = event.getY();                     
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    curX = event.getX();
                    curY = event.getY();
                    if (click && Math.abs(mx-curX)<5 && Math.abs(my-curY)<5) {
                        Log.i("miTraza","movimiento pequeño");
                        click = true;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        click = false;
                    }
                    fondo.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    gridview.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    mx = curX;
                    my = curY;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (click) {
                        int position = adaptador.getPosition(gridview, (int)mx, (int)my);
                        if (position>=0 && position<=63) {
                            gridview.performItemClick(gridview, position, 0);
                        }
                        click = false;
                    } 
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use gridview.performItemClick(gridView.getChildAt(position), position, 0);
instead of
gridview.performItemClick(gridview, position, 0);